# Preencher um gráfico chart com dados do excel

Tags: javascript, json, web-service, microsoft-excel, google-charts

Estou criando um dashboard baseado em uma planilha do excel, consegui criar os gráficos usando chart.js porém não sei um modo de fazer com que os dados sejam pegos da planilha, alguem sabe um modo de fazer isso? (os gráficos que criei, digitei o valor dos dados no código, para ver se estava funcionando, porém a planilha tem mais de 500 linhas e é atualizada diariamente, logo preciso de algo que faça a conexão com esta planilha)

Comment: Porque não exporta esses dados em CSV?

Comment: pensei nisso já, porém como disse a planilha é atualizada todos os dias, sendo assim o usuário teria que exportar manualmente para csv e depender do usuário é algo meio... logo preciso fazer com que ou eu pegue o dados diretamente do excel ou um modo de fazer o upload diario do arquivo e pegar os dados nele, caso você conheça algum modo de fazer isso, mesmo exportanto para csv pode falar também que eu pesquiso aqui e vejo se consigo fazer também, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda :)

Comment: Entendo, mas o Excel possui a funcionalidade de se conectar ao banco de dados, já pensou nisso? sempre que o usuário salvar ele atualiza um bd e daí você faz seus gráficos, nunca fiz isso para falar a verdade, mas imagino que um pouco mais de estudo você consiga. Ainda em funções do excel ele possui os macros.

Comment: Havia me esquecido desta função do Excel, grato por falar dela, irei testar aqui e ver se da para encaixar no projeto